# How to fill the empty cell with value above cell using xlwings?

Tags: xlwings

How to fill the empty cell with value above cell using xlwings?

Can you let me know the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looping through the range of cells required, and if the value of the cell is `None` (the value where the cell is empty for `cell.value`) then set the value to that of the cell 1 row above using an offset of -1 rows, 0 columns:

```py
for cell in ws.range("A2:D3"):
    if cell.value is None: # and cell.row != 1 if going to include row 1 in the range.
        cell.value = cell.offset(-1, 0).value
```

Note the comment in the `if` statement that an additional condition is required if the range is going to include the first row, because an error occurs when offsetting to row 0 which obviously doesn't exist.

Also, where the cell above is also empty, the value of the cell will not change.  But as the loop is through all cells in the row left to right, then to the next, any vertical series of consecutive empty cells will be filled with the same value from the cell above the first empty cell.